# I want to get the values of the column which are between two specific columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, between

I have a table in which I have to select values of columns which are between two columns. Suppose `column1`, `column2`, `column3` are between `column_start` and `column_end` in `table1`. Columns between `column_start` and `column_end` gets added as required.

**table1**

```
column_start | column1 | column2 | column3 | column_end
-------------------------------------------------------
     1       |    2    |    3    |    4    |     5
     8       |    5    |    6    |    4    |     2
```

Is it possible to get these `column1`, `column2`, `column3` values?

**Output:**

```
 column1 | column2 | column3
----------------------------  
   2     |    3    |    4     
   5     |    6    |    4
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you want?  Do you want the sum of these columns or the individual columns themselves?  Is the "between" requirement to be applied to each column?

Comment: you can get column details from `information_schema.COLUMNS` . hint: check `ORDINAL_POSITION` for column order

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question and have mentioned the output required. Please do check it.

Comment: What happens if 0, 1, or 2 of the columns are not in between the `column_start` and `column_end` range?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It shouldn't flash results for those columns which are not present in between these two specified column range.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As i said these columns in between specified range gets added as required while application is in progress so these column names are not known so that I cannot use these names in query.

Comment: I would say that if you don't know the column names which you want to query, then you have a design problem, and you should probably rethink your approach.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, but i have posted a solution. don't depend on the order of the columns, you can get into trouble later.

Comment: @bansi I voted you up if for no other reason than you were somehow able to decipher what the OP actually wants.

Comment: wild guess, may be my lucky day :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For sure I will rethink over my approach and will do necessary changes.

Comment: @bansi Will try that solution

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, I don't think you can do it with a single query. You can try using the following. Added comment to the code.

```
SET @schema = 'database_name_here'; -- Database name
SET @table = 'table1';              -- Table name
SET @startColumn = 'column_start';
SET @endColumn = 'column_end';

-- First get the position of both columns
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_schema=@schema AND table_name=@table AND 
    column_name=@startColumn INTO @StartPosition;

SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_schema=@schema AND table_name=@table AND 
    column_name=@endColumn INTO @endPosition;

-- get the column names from the position
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) from information_schema.COLUMNS
    where table_schema=@schema AND table_name=@table
    AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @StartPosition AND ORDINAL_POSITION < @endPosition 
    INTO @colname;

-- create a sql statement prepare and execute
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',@colname,' FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    column1 > column_start AND column1 < column_end AND
    column2 > column_start AND column2 < column_end AND
    column3 > column_start AND column3 < column_end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_start < column_end AND column1 BETWEEN column_start AND column_end THEN column1 
            WHEN column_end < column_start AND column1 BETWEEN column_end AND column_start THEN column1 
            ELSE NULL 
       END AS column1, 
       CASE WHEN column_start < column_end AND column2 BETWEEN column_start AND column_end THEN column2
            WHEN column_end < column_start AND column2 BETWEEN column_end AND column_start THEN column2 
            ELSE NULL 
       END AS column2,
       CASE WHEN column_start < column_end AND column3 BETWEEN column_start AND column_end THEN column3
            WHEN column_end < column_start AND column3 BETWEEN column_end AND column_start THEN column3 
            ELSE NULL 
       END AS column3
FROM table1;
```